# Getting Apache POI java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed when trying to read a xlsx file

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed when i try to read a xlsx file. The code is being accessed from a spring based app. I am using apache poi 3.9. With apache POI 3.8 i was getting Can't read file. The same code works fine when ran from my eclipse locally, but i get the exception when the app is deployed on my websphere server and is accessed when hosted on websphere. Can anyone please let me know what the problem is? The source code can be found below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.ReadOnlySharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;


public class XSSFListenerUtil {

    private static List<String> allColValList = null;
    private static boolean invalidTemplate = false;
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HSSFListenerUtil.class.getName()); // logger for the process.
    private static BaseViewBean baseViewBean$Session;

    /**
     * The type of the data value is indicated by an attribute on the cell.
     * The value is usually in a "v" element within the cell.
     */
    enum xssfDataType {
        BOOL, ERROR, FORMULA, INLINESTR, SSTINDEX, NUMBER,
    }

    class MyXSSFSheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        /**
         * Table with styles
         */
        private StylesTable stylesTable;

        /**
         * Table with unique strings
         */
        private ReadOnlySharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable;

        /**
         * Destination for data
         */
        //private final PrintStream output;

        /**
         * Number of columns to read starting with leftmost
         */
        private final int minColumnCount;

        // Set when V start element is seen
        private boolean vIsOpen;

        // Set when cell start element is seen;
        // used when cell close element is seen.
        private xssfDataType nextDataType;

        // Used to format numeric cell values.
        private short formatIndex;
        private String formatString;
        private final DataFormatter formatter;

        private int thisColumn = -1;
        // The last column printed to the output stream
        private int lastColumnNumber = -1;

        // Gathers characters as they are seen.
        private StringBuffer value;

        /**
         * Accepts objects needed while parsing.
         *
         * @param styles  Table of styles
         * @param strings Table of shared strings
         * @param cols    Minimum number of columns to show
         * @param target  Sink for output
         */
        public MyXSSFSheetHandler(
                StylesTable styles,
                ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings,
                int cols) {
            this.stylesTable = styles;
            this.sharedStringsTable = strings;
            this.minColumnCount = cols;
            this.value = new StringBuffer();
            this.nextDataType = xssfDataType.NUMBER;
            this.formatter = new DataFormatter();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#startElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.xml.sax.Attributes)
         */
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                                 Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            if ("inlineStr".equals(name) || "v".equals(name)) {
                vIsOpen = true;
                // Clear contents cache
                value.setLength(0);
            }
            // c => cell
            else if ("c".equals(name)) {
                // Get the cell reference
                String r = attributes.getValue("r");
                int firstDigit = -1;
                for (int c = 0; c < r.length(); ++c) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(r.charAt(c))) {
                        firstDigit = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                thisColumn = nameToColumn(r.substring(0, firstDigit));

                // Set up defaults.
                this.nextDataType = xssfDataType.NUMBER;
                this.formatIndex = -1;
                this.formatString = null;
                String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
                String cellStyleStr = attributes.getValue("s");
                if ("b".equals(cellType))
                    nextDataType = xssfDataType.BOOL;
                else if ("e".equals(cellType))
                    nextDataType = xssfDataType.ERROR;
                else if ("inlineStr".equals(cellType))
                    nextDataType = xssfDataType.INLINESTR;
                else if ("s".equals(cellType))
                    nextDataType = xssfDataType.SSTINDEX;
                else if ("str".equals(cellType))
                    nextDataType = xssfDataType.FORMULA;
                else if (cellStyleStr != null) {
                    // It's a number, but almost certainly one with a special style or format 
                    int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(cellStyleStr);
                    XSSFCellStyle style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
                    this.formatIndex = style.getDataFormat();
                    this.formatString = style.getDataFormatString();
                    if (this.formatString == null)
                        this.formatString = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(this.formatIndex);
                }
            }

        }
        StringBuffer columnvalue = new StringBuffer();

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#endElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
         */
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                throws SAXException {

            String thisStr = null;

            // v => contents of a cell
            if ("v".equals(name)) {
                // Process the value contents as required.
                // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
                switch (nextDataType) {

                    case BOOL:
                        char first = value.charAt(0);
                        thisStr = first == '0' ? "FALSE" : "TRUE";
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        thisStr = "\"ERROR:" + value.toString() + '"';
                        break;

                    case FORMULA:
                        // A formula could result in a string value, so always add double-quote characters.
                        thisStr = '"' + value.toString() + '"';
                        break;

                    case INLINESTR:
                        XSSFRichTextString rtsi = new XSSFRichTextString(value.toString());
                        thisStr = '"' + rtsi.toString() + '"';
                        break;

                    case SSTINDEX:
                        String sstIndex = value.toString();
                        try {
                            int idx = Integer.parseInt(sstIndex);
                            XSSFRichTextString rtss = new XSSFRichTextString(sharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(idx));
                            thisStr = '"' + rtss.toString() + '"';
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            log.error("Failed to parse SST index '" + sstIndex + "': " + ex.toString());
                            throw new SAXException("Failed to parse SST index '" + sstIndex + "': " + ex.toString());
                        }
                        break;

                    case NUMBER:
                        String n = value.toString();
                        if (this.formatString != null)
                            thisStr = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double.parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex, this.formatString);
                        else
                            thisStr = n;
                        break;

                    default:
                        thisStr = "(TODO: Unexpected type: " + nextDataType + ")";
                        break;
                }

                // Output after we've seen the string contents
                // Emit commas for any fields that were missing on this row
                if (lastColumnNumber == -1) {
                    lastColumnNumber = 0;
                }
                for (int i = lastColumnNumber; i < thisColumn; ++i){
                    //output.print(',');
                    columnvalue.append(",");
                }
                // Might be an empty string.
                columnvalue.append(thisStr);

                // Update column
                if (thisColumn > -1)
                    lastColumnNumber = thisColumn;

            } else if ("row".equals(name)) {

                // Print out any missing commas if needed
                if (minColumns > 0) {
                    // Columns are 0 based
                    if (lastColumnNumber == -1) {
                        lastColumnNumber = 0;
                    }
                    for (int i = lastColumnNumber; i < (this.minColumnCount); i++) {
                        //output.print(',');
                        columnvalue.append(",");
                    }
                }

                // We're onto a new row
                if(!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(columnvalue.toString())){
                    String completeVal = columnvalue.toString().replaceAll("\"", "");
                    allColValList.add(completeVal);
                }
                columnvalue  = new StringBuffer("");
                lastColumnNumber = -1;
            }

        }

        /**
         * Captures characters only if a suitable element is open.
         * Originally was just "v"; extended for inlineStr also.
         */
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            if (vIsOpen)
                value.append(ch, start, length);
        }

        /**
         * Converts an Excel column name like "C" to a zero-based index.
         *
         * @param name
         * @return Index corresponding to the specified name
         */
        private int nameToColumn(String name) {
            int column = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {
                int c = name.charAt(i);
                column = (column + 1) * 26 + c - 'A';
            }
            return column;
        }

    }

    private OPCPackage xlsxPackage;
    private int minColumns;

    /**
     *
     * @param pkg        The XLSX package to process
     * @param output     The PrintStream to output the CSV to
     * @param minColumns The minimum number of columns to output, or -1 for no minimum
     */
    public XSSFListenerUtil(OPCPackage pkg, int minCol, ArrayList<String> colList, BaseViewBean baseViewBean$Session) {
        this.xlsxPackage = pkg;
        this.minColumns = minCol;
        XSSFListenerUtil.allColValList = colList;
        XSSFListenerUtil.baseViewBean$Session = baseViewBean$Session;
    }

    /**
     * Parses and shows the content of one sheet
     * using the specified styles and shared-strings tables.
     *
     * @param styles
     * @param strings
     * @param sheetInputStream
     */
    public void processSheet(
            StylesTable styles,
            ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings,
            InputStream sheetInputStream)
            throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
        SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        ContentHandler handler = new MyXSSFSheetHandler(styles, strings, this.minColumns);
        sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
        sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
    }

    /**
     * Initiates the processing of the XLS workbook file to CSV.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws OpenXML4JException
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     * @throws SAXException
     */
    public void process()
            throws IOException, OpenXML4JException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(xlsxPackage);
        XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(xlsxPackage);
        StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();
        int index = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            InputStream stream = iter.next();
            processSheet(styles, strings, stream);
            stream.close();
            ++index;
        }
    }

    public static void parseAndRetrieveExcelDetails(String filePath, InvestmentDimDao investmentDao, 
                            BaseViewBean baseViewBean$Session, ActionMessages errors, boolean invalidTemplateIdentifier) throws Exception{

        int minColumns = -1;
        invalidTemplate = invalidTemplateIdentifier;
        ArrayList<String> initialList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filePath, PackageAccess.READ);
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filePath);
        XSSFListenerUtil xssfSheetProcessor = new XSSFListenerUtil(pkg, minColumns, initialList, baseViewBean$Session);
        xssfSheetProcessor.process();

        validateAndExtractExcelData();

        log.info("Finished processing all records");
        if(invalidTemplate){
            errors.add("failure", new ActionMessage("secaccess.file.invaliddata"));
        }else{
            log.info("All records parsed successfully");
        }

        allColValList.clear();
        allColValList = null;
        pkg.close();
        System.gc();
    }

    private static void validateAndExtractExcelData() throws NumberFormatException {
        int rowCnt = 1;
        int colCnt = 0;
        ExcelListenerBean listenerBean;
        ExcelListenerBean bean;
        Map <String, ExcelListenerBean> excelRecords = new TreeMap<String, ExcelListenerBean>();
        for(String colVal : allColValList) {
            if(rowCnt==1 && !AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.G_L_CALC_HEADER1.equals(colVal)) {
                invalidTemplate = true;
            }
            if(rowCnt==2 && !AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.G_L_CALC_HEADER2.equals(colVal) & !invalidTemplate) {
                invalidTemplate = true;
            }
            if(rowCnt==3 && !AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.G_L_CALC_HEADER3.equals(colVal) & !invalidTemplate) {
                invalidTemplate = true;
            }
            if(rowCnt > 3 && !invalidTemplate) {
                listenerBean = new ExcelListenerBean(AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.SQL_TYPE);

                String[] allValues = colVal.split(",");
                for(String cellContents : allValues){

                    switch (colCnt) {
                        case 0:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean = new ExcelListenerBean(AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.SQL_TYPE);
                                listenerBean.setId(rowCnt);
                                listenerBean.setShortName(cellContents);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setFmrCusip(cellContents);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdShares(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdPrice(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdBuySell(cellContents);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdCommRate(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdCommission(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdFees(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents.toString()) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents.toString())){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setIncorrectTrdNet(Double.valueOf(cellContents.toString()));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdShares(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdPrice(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdBuySell(cellContents);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdCommRate(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdCommission(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdFees(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            if(GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(cellContents) || !GenericValidator.isDouble(cellContents)){
                                invalidTemplate = true;
                                break;
                            }else{
                                listenerBean.setCorrectionTrdNet(Double.valueOf(cellContents));
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    colCnt++;
                }

                bean = excelRecords.get(listenerBean.getShortName());
                if (bean != null){
                    listenerBean.setAcctGainLossAmt(new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(bean.getAcctGainLossAmt()) + listenerBean.getCorrectionTrdNet() + listenerBean.getIncorrectTrdNet()).toPlainString());
                } else {
                    listenerBean.setAcctGainLossAmt(new BigDecimal(listenerBean.getCorrectionTrdNet() + listenerBean.getIncorrectTrdNet()).toPlainString());
                }

                excelRecords.put(listenerBean.getShortName(), listenerBean);
            }
            colCnt = 0;
            rowCnt++;
        }

        baseViewBean$Session.setExcelRecLst(new ArrayList<ExcelListenerBean>(excelRecords.values()));
        log.info("Number of records for update is "+excelRecords.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Full stacktrace would help.  Also, you are attempting to read a package based on a file path, does the xlsx file exist on the websphere server and does the websphere instance have sufficient permissions to read that file?

Comment: No, the file path is my local system path. Will the server not be able to handle it?

Comment: The file path would be local to the server.  The server wouldn't be able see the disk on your local machine.  To handle a file on the server, you'd have to upload it first.

Comment: @beny23 - Thanks for the update. I will try to pass the inputstream instead. Should work. I will update you after i do my  test.

Comment: It worked, changing the file path to inputstream helped. I was under the impression that providing the file path would work, but i forgot to think about the fact that the server wouldn't be able see a file on local machine instead it has to be uploaded first. Thanks beny23 for bringing this point

Answer (score 2):

I was running into same problem but then I realize that my file name was TestData.xlsx and I was using TestData.csv